# RichTextBox get string from Index

Tags: vb.net

how can I get string from index in richtextbox, like that:

```
 MsgBox(RichTextBox1.Text(1, 5))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RichTextBox.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx), which has [String.Substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx).  Thus it should look like:

```
Dim s As String = RichTextBox1.Text.Substring(1, 5)
```